# python find exception message (with ast?)

Tags: python

I want to compile a list of all messages my program could present to a user, specifically all errors (to be able to quality-check the wording).
Let's assume I have my own exception class

```
class MyException( Exception ):
    pass
```

And I would want to find programmatically all instances where I

```
raise MyException( "This is a baadly worded message with typo." )
```

Is there an elegant python way to retrieve:

- the message
- the line number
- the (member) function name that raises the exception?

Ideally, it would even work with cases like

```
msg = "My really long error message\n"
msg += "Where I explain too much to fit it directly into the raise call"
raise MyException( msg )
```

Comment: Second case it totally out because in order to figure out the result you must execute the program.

Comment: So you want a traceback along with your custom exception?

Comment: There's probably two solutions: `inspect` + `grep`, and `compile` + `grep`.

Comment: `gettext` commandline tool can extract all string literals that are passed as args to gettext function, that is somewhat similar, since it is open source you can check how they do it. It only works for `_("str")` and `gettext("str")` but maybe you can modify it to look for `MyException`

Comment: @cat
I really don't understand what you mean - inspect (the stdlib package) could help me how? otherwise, byte-compiling would help in what way?

Comment: @Andrey I think that gettext is really going in the right direction for me; I was just hoping that using the python ast package to build the "abstract syntax tree" of python itself would facilitate the search more easily. Generally, I know a lot more about my code (since it's python!) then what gettext can assume.

Comment: @TimO you can definitely do it with ast but I have a feeling that you will waste more time building such extraction tool then you approach this problem other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to localize your Python application.

In this case have a loot at [gettext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) as is a very powerful localization framework, one that is used by most open-source projects, not only Python ones.

Comment: This is not exactly what I had in mind, but it seems to be the best out-of-the-box fit for the issue. Also special thanks to Andrey who suggested this in the comments to the question.

Comment: Thanks TimO, betting on gettext toolstack I a safe bet. I have few good years doing i18n and l10n work, and gettext is on my fav list.